# Labels on axis are overwritten

Tags: r

I'm sorry for asking this question, but I already googled and searched here but I found nothing useful (that means lots of different functions for drawing the plot, but no one with my problem).
I have a vector containing the data I have to plot (named "rmse"), and a vector containing the names of the columns on the x-axis (named "nomi"). I simply want to plot the data with the labels on the x-axis rotated of 90°, due to space problems.
I found this useful site: http://harding.edu/fmccown/r/
Looking at it, I found how to rotate the labels on the axis, but, even though I have 12 columns, I have 6 columns with an overwritten label and 6 columns without label.

Here's my code:

```
library(lattice)
library(gstat)

nomi<-c("Quota","No Quota","Mare","No Mare","Slope","No Slope","Terreno","No Terreno","Facet","No Facet","Po","No Po")
rmse<-c(1.79,1.97,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.82,1.80,1.83,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.81)
g_range <- range(0, rmse)
plot(rmse, type='h',axes=F, ann=F)
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=F)
text(axTicks(1),par("usr")[3],  srt=90, adj=1, labels=nomi,  xpd=T, cex=0.8)
axis(2, las=1)
box()
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Do you know what am I doing wrong? I know it's a simple questions, but I'm quite a beginner and sometimes I need help :)

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: Any reason why you're trying to draw the axis labels using `text` rather than simply using the `labels` argument in `axis`?

Comment: whats with requiring lattice and gstat? It's because `axTicks(1)` gives `# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12` and not 1:12 like you need

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm using [code]text[/code] only because I've seen it in the link, I read the reference of axis (with ?axis) but I didn't find how to rotate the labels. But for me it's ok even if I use the labels argument. I'm requiring gstat and lattice because I use it later, but not for the plot.  If it's more clear I can edit and remove lattice and gstat.

Comment: Sorry rawr, I tried to work a little on axTicks. I've seen that it has 4 values (1,2,3,4), I tried them all but it didn't work (the situation remains the same or, with the options 2 and 4, I have all the labels on only one column). I tried also to use the "labels" argument in "axis", but it doesn't support "srt".

Comment: I was just saying that `axTicks` wasn't meant for what you were trying to do. you specified `at` in axis to make the ticks so you need to use the same coordinates to get the text to line up. axTicks returned 6 coordinates and you gave 12 labels, so those coordinates were recycled and thus the labels were overplotted. your solution works fine but, you are correct in that if you need more specific rotation (ie, -90, 45 degrees, etc), you have to use `srt` in text since `las` will not suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved! It was enough to add "las=2" as argument of axis, thanks to joran to have suggested me that I can avoid "text" ;)

```
nomi<-c("Quota","No Quota","Mare","No Mare","Slope","No Slope","Terreno","No Terreno","Facet","No Facet","Po","No Po")
rmse<-c(1.79,1.97,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.82,1.80,1.83,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.81)
g_range <- range(0, rmse)
plot(rmse, type='h',axes=F, ann=F)
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=nomi, las=2)
axis(2, las=1) 
box()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use by ggplot2 command to produce the chart

```
dt <- data.frame(
  rownum = 1:length(nomi),
  nomi=c("Quota","No Quota","Mare","No Mare","Slope","No Slope","Terreno","No Terreno","Facet","No Facet","Po","No Po"),
  rmse=c(1.79,1.97,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.82,1.80,1.83,1.82,1.84,1.82,1.81)
  )

library(ggplot2)                    

ggplot(dt) + aes(x =reorder(nomi,rownum), y = rmse) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, face="bold", colour="black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(name="" )
```

[image]